# Limit the number of results using preg_match_all PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Is there any way to limit the number of matches that will be returned using `preg_match_all`?

So for example, I want to match only the first 20 `<p>` tags on a web page but there are 100 `<p>` tags.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

No, the computation of the `preg_match_all` result set cannot be limited. You can only limit the results afterwards with [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) or [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) (this would require *PREG_SET_ORDER*):

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$firstMatches = array_slice($matches, 0, 20);
```

But besides that, you shouldn’t use regular expressions to parse HTML anyway. Although modern regular expressions engines are not regular any more and can process an irregular language like HTML, it is too error prone. Better use an appropriate HTML parser instead like the one of [PHP’s DOM library](http://php.net/book.dom). Then just use a counter to only get up to 20 matches:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);
$counter = 20;
$matches = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $elem) {
    if ($counter-- <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    $matches[] = $elem;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Gumbo, this DOM stuff is really useful. Never tried using that instead of reg ex on HTML so will give it a go!

Comment: @SiQ: Note that *DOMDocument* implements the DOM as specified by W3C and thus is quite extensive; if you just need to read the DOM, you can also try [*SimpleXML*](http://php.net/book.simplexml).

Comment: Your DOMDocument solution limits the code after the fact, as well, doesn't it?  It doesn't set a limit, but ignores the extra tags that it gathered.

Answer (score 3):

```
$matches = array();   
preg_match_all ( $pattern , $subject , $matches );
$twenty = array_slice($matches , 0, 20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just match all and slice the resulting array:

```
$allMatches = array ();
$numMatches = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $allMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$limit = 20;
$limitedResults = $allMatches;
if($numMatches > $limit)
{
   $limitedResults = array_slice($allMatches, 0, $limit);
}

// Use $limitedResults here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx) library:

```
pattern('<p>')->match($yourHtml)->only(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the true answer; the most memory-efficient way.
Use **reference assignment** via `preg_replace_callback()` instead.

```
<?php

$matches = [];

preg_replace_callback(
    '~<p(?:\s.*?)?>(?:.*?)</p>~s',
    function (array $match) use (&$matches) {
        $matches[] = $match[0];
    },
    $html,
    20,
    $_
);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the p tags have attributes or their innerhtml spans more than one line.  The rabbit hole begins.  Please advise against the use of regex when parsing html.

Comment: Also, by my count, `preg_replace_callback()` has a max of 5 parameters. (`$pattern, $callback, $subject, $limit, and $count`) `PREG_SET_ORDER` is not necessary and will not be honored. I also don't think declaring the count variable is valuable for this case. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @mickmackusa My snippet was not for this question, sorry. That was for my job.

Comment: @mickmackusa This is documentation bug. php-src says it has 6 parameters. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cebe750f460b8060ab21ae1e21980098f3f5b8e2/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L2385-L2393

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for letting me know.  Even still, the last two params are not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on @Gumbo's great advice to use a DOM parser instead of regex, the following snippet will use a XPath query with a `position()` condition to limit the targeted tags.

Code: ([Demo targeting 4 of 5 p tags](https://3v4l.org/ZVRc6))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <p class="classy">1
</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p data-p="<p>notatag</p>">3</p>
    <span data-monkeywrench='<p'>z</span>
    <p
 data-p="<p>notatag</p>">4</p>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//p[position() <= 4]') as $p) {
    echo var_export($p->nodeValue, true) , "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'1
'
---
'2'
---
'3'
---
'4'
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) does have an `offset` parameter, and also a `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag which, when combined, can be used to get the "next match".

This is mainly useful if you don't want to get all results and then `array_slice()` a portion off :o)

EDIT:
Ok, here's some code (not tested or used in any way):

```
$offset = 0;
$matches = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $results = preg_match('/<p(?:.*?)>/', $string, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
    if (empty($results)) {
        break;
    } else {
        $matches[] = $results[0][0];
        $offset += $results[0][1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `preg_match_all()` and discard the matches you're not interested in, or you can use a loop with `preg_match()`.  The second option would be better if you're concern about the expense of scanning a large string.

This example limits to 2 matches, when there are actually 3 in the entire string:

```
<?php

$str = "ab1ab2ab3ab4c";

for ($offset = 0, $n = 0;
        $n < 2 && preg_match('/b([0-9])/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
        ++$n, $offset = $matches[0][1] + 1) {

        var_dump($matches);
}
```

Really a `while` loop would probably have been clearer than a `for` loop on reflection ;)